# Искомый элемент одинаковый, но имеет другое разрешение

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img_rgb = cv.imread('3213.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('SXfPYQxyovLFfile.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Скрипт отлично отрабатывает если искомый элемент одинакового размера. Не изменять же мне размер искомого элемента что-бы найти один и тотже фрагмент. Есть решение более адекватное?
Допустим если я буду искать свою аватарку на скрине, то если она будет оригинального размера я её не найду.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы, помимо кода, Вы словами пояснили, что делает Ваш код, какие он элементы ищет и где.

Comment: @V-Mor, код ищет картинку в картинке.

Comment: matchTemplate ищет элементы инвариантные только к сдвигу. 
Если  нужно еще и масштабирование, то для этого используются признаки типа SIFT, ORB и др.